# Button with Icon and Label

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Hello I'm currently looking for a way to display a button with icon and label.

I want the icon to be on the left side and the label left-aligned on the right side of the Icon.

I don't think this is possible in openedge but maybe one has an idea for this.

I'm using an abl-frame and the button needs to be generated dynamically

Comment: Never done it, but I'm pretty sure you can embed your ABL-frame in a .Net form to keep changes to a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

I have a very ugly solution for you:

Create an image containing the entire face of the button. Icon and text included. Perhaps not a beautiful solution but you won't need to use .Net.

Basically it will just add the `IMAGE-UP` attribute for the button.

```
DEFINE BUTTON BUTTON-3 
     IMAGE-UP FILE "c:/temp/button.png":U
     LABEL "Button 3" 
     SIZE 48 BY 4.29.
```

button.png:

[image: Button image]

Add that image to your button.

[image: Property sheet]

Result:

[image]

If you need to set different pictures based on contrast you will need to check Registry for contrast setting. That can be done something like this:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cContrast AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

LOAD "Control Panel" BASE-KEY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER".  
USE "Control Panel".

GET-KEY-VALUE SECTION "Accessibility\HighContrast" KEY "Flags" VALUE cContrast.

UNLOAD "Control Panel".

IF cContrast = "126" THEN 
    MESSAGE "Low contrast" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
ELSE IF cContrast = "127" THEN 
    MESSAGE "High contrast" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Comment: :-) We use this for our classic buttons. With different images for different languages we even have a button image generator that will take the image, add the translated text, snip it and save it to an image file... (snipping in C#)

Comment: @StefanDrissen It might be somewhat of a hack but it works! :-)

Comment: Thats what we were using befor, unfortunately this method is not working with the high contrast feature of windows. One of our clients is colorblind so we need to display the colors which the user configured in windows. We neither can create high contrast images because we have a set of defined Icons which I have to use. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Why can you not create an extra set of high contrast images? Either check registry (or so) or a db setting to select icon set A or icon set B, it's just as hacky as the rest of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not on a completely obsolete version of Progress OpenEdge then you can use .Net controls, the visual designer in Progress Developer Studio for OpenEdge (PDSOE) will let you drag and drop the following together:

[image]

This generates the following source code (which you can also use to generate form creation):

```
USING Progress.Lang.*.
USING Progress.Windows.Form.

BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

CLASS button INHERITS Form: 

   DEFINE PRIVATE VARIABLE button1 AS System.Windows.Forms.Button NO-UNDO.
   DEFINE PRIVATE VARIABLE components AS System.ComponentModel.IContainer NO-UNDO.


   CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC button (  ):


      SUPER().
      InitializeComponent().
      THIS-OBJECT:ComponentsCollection:ADD(THIS-OBJECT:components).
      CATCH e AS Progress.Lang.Error:
         UNDO, THROW e.
      END CATCH.

   END CONSTRUCTOR.

   METHOD PRIVATE VOID InitializeComponent(  ):

      /* NOTE: The following method is automatically generated.

      We strongly suggest that the contents of this method only be modified using the
      Visual Designer to avoid any incompatible modifications.

      Modifying the contents of this method using a code editor will invalidate any support for this file. */
      @VisualDesigner.FormMember (NeedsInitialize="true").
      DEFINE VARIABLE resources AS Progress.Util.ResourceManager NO-UNDO.
      resources = NEW Progress.Util.ResourceManager("button").
      THIS-OBJECT:button1 = NEW System.Windows.Forms.Button().
      THIS-OBJECT:SuspendLayout().
      /*  */
      /* button1 */
      /*  */
      THIS-OBJECT:button1:Image = CAST(resources:GetObject("button1.Image"), System.Drawing.Image).
      THIS-OBJECT:button1:ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment:MiddleLeft.
      THIS-OBJECT:button1:Location = NEW System.Drawing.Point(13, 212).
      THIS-OBJECT:button1:Name = "button1".
      THIS-OBJECT:button1:Size = NEW System.Drawing.Size(108, 42).
      THIS-OBJECT:button1:TabIndex = 0.
      THIS-OBJECT:button1:Text = "Exit".
      THIS-OBJECT:button1:TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment:MiddleRight.
      THIS-OBJECT:button1:UseCompatibleTextRendering = TRUE.
      THIS-OBJECT:button1:UseVisualStyleBackColor = TRUE.
      /*  */
      /* button */
      /*  */
      THIS-OBJECT:ClientSize = NEW System.Drawing.Size(292, 266).
      THIS-OBJECT:Controls:Add(THIS-OBJECT:button1).
      THIS-OBJECT:Name = "button".
      THIS-OBJECT:Text = "button".
      THIS-OBJECT:ResumeLayout(FALSE).
      CATCH e AS Progress.Lang.Error:
         UNDO, THROW e.
      END CATCH.
   END METHOD.

   DESTRUCTOR PUBLIC button ( ):

   END DESTRUCTOR.

END CLASS.
```

The drag and drop method will also by default create a resx file which is an xml file containing the resources used, the image is encoded in there:

```
  <data mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64" name="button1.Image" type="System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing">
    <value>
        iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAIAAABvFaqvAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAO
        wgAADsIBFShKgAAAAJFJREFUOE/N0EEOgCAMRFEP4tL738wz1CaDQYa2FmThX5FIH8gmi/otdO4HFtNV
        aNSikfproxZtbt4ob/Xb+LEzkHmeAcWW95Uh5O0OjslCIDxFsyHtORMTyIU0DGcULYK0pKK93AjK/I3o
        Ip+gsrojuo+hYCC2Gig+E3lchTIKMq0Ceed49fvtx860DKIWQSIXxapUG1GIZgoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
</value>
```

When generating your forms with code you do not need the resx files and can load images etc from the file system.